# Finger blood tests in Gattaca

Tags: gattaca

In Gattacca, all the (presumably) valid people have their fingers constantly punctured for a blood test.

That seems so problematic. Puncturing the skin allows pathogen agents to enter the body. And it seems the puncturing machines use the same needles again and again, this would facilitate contagion of diseases. Even if these people has an enhanced immunity system, it can't be perfect. Natural selection will eventually evolve pathogens to be able to handle it.

Moreover, even small wounds hurt a bit. Using a computer keyboard after having your finger punctured seems annoying.

And I don't see any advantage. Sure, it can filter out invalids. But I think it would be more reasonable to do this test only once as part of the hiring process, and let the daily test be less invasive, e.g. test fingerprints or saliva.

Then, what was the reasoning of these tests?

Comment: People with type I diabetes or severe type II diabetes have to perform finger-prick blood tests daily, sometimes multiple times per day.

Comment: With respect tocontamination, could the needle simply be heat-sterilized after each use?

Comment: @Praxis Good point. But in that case it's justified because not doing the tests could put them in severe danger. It's not the case of the characters in the film.

Comment: @Adamant - Theoretically yes, but with a fine "fingerstick" needle, using heat sterilisation would make it brittle and you'd lose the fine point after only one or two rotations. Better to simply use disposables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First up, many people do a [finger-prick test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerstick) on a daily basis (in some cases several times daily) to test their blood sugar. It's relatively painless and doesn't impede typing, especially when done with a small needle.

> *They filter through a row of channels supervised by SECURITY  GUARDS.
> Each channel contains a computerized security device, featuring a slim
> groove in which the employee places a finger under the watchful eye of
> a Security Guard.*
>
> *Jerome gives a polite nod to a Guard as he places his index finger in
> the groove.  **His fingertip is jabbed with the finest of needles** and a
> minute blood sample taken.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Gattaca - Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Gattaca.html)</sup></sub>

Second, there's no reason to believe (and in fact every reason to not believe) that they were using **the same needles over and over again** when it would be surpassingly simple to have it dispose of used needles into a 'sharps' bin.

In the opening sequence we see the machine queuing up new (and presumably sterile) needles each time someone steps up to the machine. Given the need for an utterly unadulterated genetic sample, using a disposable needle each time would seem essential.

[image]

---

As to why a *blood test* was required (as opposed to a saliva swab), the chances of a contaminated sample are much lower and it's far harder for an invalid to get onto the premises. We also see that fingerprints can be forged with relative ease.

Comment: I think the movie shows the inside of the puncturing machines and the needles were reused, but I don't remember it with detail.

Comment: @Oriol - Good point. I've made a gif to demonstrate the workings.

Comment: Maybe the purple glow is part of a UV light that sterilizes the needle?

Comment: @CBredlow - I believe that's the scanny thing that checks the DNA.

Comment: @Valorum I was going to include that exact same gif, but you are too fast and beat me :)

Comment: @Oriol - Gotta be quick 'round here.